# Mysql.connector in Pycharm

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pycharm, connector

I am trying to use `mysql.connector` in Pycharm (with 2.7.3), but I'm incapable of importing it. It imports perfectly in IDLE; it's installed under /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector , but I cannot figure out how to import it into PyCharm when I 'Add Local'.

Comment: Hey did you ever find a solution? Thanks in advance